# Laravel Eloquent where statement returns no attributes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, where-clause

So from my previous post, I was advised to start using Eloquent models, which I did.

My end goal, is to print out specific gifts, that belongs to that specific box.

**Migrations:**

gift_items:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('gift_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->float('unit_price');
            $table->integer('units_owned');
        });
    }
```

gift_campaigns:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('gift_campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreignId('user_foreignK')->constrained('users');
            $table->integer('gift_item_count')->nullable();
            $table->string('status');
            $table->date('dispatch_date');
            $table->date('delivery_date');
        });
    }
```

Pivot table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('campaigns_gifts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('gift_id')->constrained('gift_items');
            $table->foreignId('campaign_id')->constrained('gift_campaigns');
        });
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
function box($id){
        $data = Campaign::with('gifts')->where('id', $id)->get();
        return view('DBqueries.boxView', ['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

Error that I receive using this way:[image: error]

Seems like the updated version is trying to call the gift_campaigns table id, instead of the pivots table campaign_id.

Once again, I need that Request $id would match the pivots table campaign_id, and print out all of the gifts that this specific id holds

Comment: I see your relations seem pretty much messed up, you need some cleaning here. first of all add code not images of code, and for images use links don't add too much images directly to question. This is making it difficult to focus at one point. try cleaning this up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all as I sense the `campaigns_gifts` is a pivot table for `campaigns` and `gifts` having a Many-to-Many relation. You are doing it completely against the conventions of Laravel.

- You generally do not use a Model for pivot table.
- You generally do not fetch data from the pivot table directly. Instead use the relation on one of the related Models.

*Note: Laravel does allow a Model for a Pivot, and you can query the pivot table directly, just [check the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).*

## The correct way:

### Pivot

Make a pivot table (that you already have) with column `gift_id` and `campaign_id`. i.e., the convention for naming keys as `[table_name_singular]_[primary_key_on_table]`

### Model

One each model, define relationship for the other data as:

`Gift.php` Model:

```
public function campaign() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Campaign::class, 'campaign_gift');
}
```

`Campaign.php` Model:

```
public function gifts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Gift::class,'campaign_gift'); 
}
```

since gift have a `hasMany` relation, the `gifts` table must contain a foreign key to `campaigns` table named `campaign_id` (same as the one on pivot).

### Controller

Now in your controller:

```
function box($id){
    $data = Campaign::where('id',$id)->with('gifts')->get();
    return view('DBqueries.boxView', ['data'=>$data]);
}
```

You don't need to tell Laravel which columns, tables etc are you referring to, as long as you follow the conventions, Laravel will magically do things that otherwise would have been much more painful.

Comment: Correct, it is a pivot table (couldn't think of a better way to have a many to many relation).

I am thankful for your points in regards to Laravel conventions.

The reason of this pivot table, is in order to match the box ID (request) and the campaign_id, in order to print all gifts that belongs to that specific campaign.

Basically, your written solution seems to ignore my pivot table, which is the main key here.

Comment: pivot table cannot contain anything other than foreign keys of related tables. You should keep other data in it's own table and pivot will contain the foreign keys of both of these tables. when you fetch using ```with()``` Laravel will automatically fetch data from other table. If you do anything out of convention, you'll have to do everything manually. i.e., ```gift_foreignK``` in your pivot will cause confusion for Laravel and require you to feed the key explicitly.

Comment: Correct, pivot tables only holds the foreign keys at the moment of these relates tables. But using this way, it simply does not find my columns within the database (I did rename as you said, and done the migration) It seems that it is calling the gift_campaign table instead of the pivot one

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gift_items.campaign_id' in 'where clause'
select
  *
from
  `gift_items`
where
  `gift_items`.`campaign_id` in (1)

Comment: can you update your question with Migrations for all these tables? including pivot. Also make sure you are calling the ```Campaign``` or ```Gift``` model.

Comment: Updated the question with migrations and the current implementation of the suggestion previously. It has the relations that you have mentioned previously.

Comment: Both of your tables do not contain any foreign ID that could identify what belongs to what. your ```gift_items``` table must contain a foreign key to ```gift_campaigns``` without that pivot is just a blind table. it knows the gift belongs to campaign but doesn't know which gift belongs to what campaign.
To understand this consider this: Your ```where``` fetches the gifts, you call ```with('campaign')``` now Laravel looks for a column named ```campaign_id``` on ```gift_item```'s fetched data to reference it on pivot and then go and fetch the campaign. But since there's no such column it fails.

Comment: gift_items table can't have a foreign key on each row, since these gifts do not repeat. Each gift is unique, and it only holds one item each (They can't repeat, and simply have a different foreign key). Due to this reason, I have created a pivot table, which would show, what campaign has what gift (Since many campaigns can use the same gift). Neither campaign, neither gifts have repeating cases of them.

Comment: Maybe if I tell more about the idea, it will make more sense:

First, I can create gifts that would be held within my database (Since I do not know, which campaign will take which gift, I can't assign any foreign keys yet).

Then, I go ahead, and create a campaign. In this campaign, I can assign random gifts, from gift_table.

This assigned information is being held within the pivot table.

The issue appears here, once I try to print each individuals campaign gifts.

Comment: You should suspect the naming for your tables is terribly wrong. Laravel won't identify the pivot since the table names are entirely different from what we have on pivot. change ```gift_items``` to ```gifts``` and ```gift_campaigns``` to ```campaigns``` the pivot will be ```campaign_gift``` (singular) not ```campaigns_gifts``` the columns are correct. See if this works.

Comment: I do not realise how much the Laravel relies on the naming of so many things, although, even after changing the naming, it still tries to call the campaign_id from gifts table (same issue). 
It seems that this specific implementation can only work, if the gifts table has a foreign key

Comment: This specific situation, basically forced me to try and think, that I can simply equal campaigns table with pivots table campaign_id, and with this matching I can print specific gifts, that have a foreign key in the pivot table on that specific row.

Comment: This is what I am trying to tell. When you fetch data from ```gifts``` table using```with('campaign')``` Laravel will ask the data to provide ```campaign_id``` which it will not find since there's no such column, Laravel cannot identify which foreign key are you referring on pivot since there can be many foreign keys on origin table. One more thing, since you said the gift exists before campaign, you can create a migration to modify ```gifts``` table to add foreign key later.

Comment: So basically, my idea cannot be implemented, since I can’t create foreign Keys on gifts table, due to the fact, that gifts are being created earlier than campgains themselves? I could easily force the client to first create campaigns, and then manually write each gift that belong to that campaign,  but picking a gift from already existing ones seems to be way more relevant.

Comment: It definitely can be implemented, you can simply add foreign key to ```campaigns``` table and fetch gifts from there since a many to many relation is s two-way path, tell me what are you trying to fetch? All gifts that belong to a specific campaign or all campaign which contain a gift?

Comment: I am trying to fetch all gifts that belongs to specific campgain. Box = campaign, therefore, client opens the box and see’s all of the gifts that are inside that specific campaign.

Comment: try ```Gift::with(['campaign' => function($query){ $query->where('id',$id)}])``` the closure syntax will allow you to fetch records that match to a specific campaign from the id you are receiving from Request.

Comment: This query seems to be a bit too extreme for me, since I have no clue what does what haha, anyway, it seems that you can't pass the $id like this, since it is not defined anymore (not taking it from the passed elements).

Comment: My bad, try this: 
```Gift::with(['campaign' => function($query) use ($id) { $query->where('id',$id)}])```
you need to extend the scope of ```$id``` to function.

Comment: Yes, it corrected the error, thank you.

Although, back to the same issue as I had in the beginning of the thread, where it does not return any attributes. dd does not show, that it would have any attributes within itself. It catches the model, but model itself has nothing inside. I do have all of the tables filled with data.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to simply recreate the logic here, create an additional foreignK to campaigns, and assign each gift to it, while creating multiple entries on the campaigns table. This way, even the pivot table would be avoided, simply the convenience from client side would be a mess

Comment: Don't. Lets work it out without requiring foreign ID. Lets continue in chat.

Comment: *"You never need a Model for a Pivot table"* - Sorry, but that statement is wrong: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models. In general, you don't need a model for a Pivot Table, but saying "never" is not correct; Laravel supports this, and there are cases where you'd need (or want) to query the pivot directly.

Comment: Hey @TimLewis  thank you for pointing that out. Edits are always welcome.

Comment: Edit added. I figured I would add as a comment first, to avoid modifying your already accepted answer out of the blue. Cheers!